# Trigonometry equation $\sin2x-\sin3x=\sin7x-\sin8x$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to solve this equation, but I got a different answer from the book. In the book there is only one solution ($x=36°k$), but when I solved, I got 3 solutions ($x=36°k$,$x=72°k$,$x=360°k$).

```
Sin2x-sin3x = sin7x-sin8x
Sin2x-sin3x-sin7x+sin8x=0
Sin2x+sin8x-1(sin3x+sin7x)=0
2*sin5x*cos3x-1(2sin5x*cos2x)=0
2sin5x*cos3x-2sin5x*cos2x=0
Sin5x*cos3x-sin5x*cos2x=0
Sin5x(cos3x-cos2x)=0

Sin5x=0
5x=180k
X=36k

Cos3x-cos2x=0
Cos3x=cos2x

3x=2x+360k
X=360k

5x=360k
X=72k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all the same answer, since $72k$ is the same as $36(2k)$, and $360k$ is the same as $36(10k)$. (Presumably $k \in \mathbb Z$ here.)

So you got the same answer as the book, just redundantly.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice, given that $$\sin 2x-\sin 3x=\sin 7x-\sin 8x$$
>   $$(\sin 8x+\sin 2x)-(\sin 7x+\sin 3x)$$
>   $$2\sin\left(\frac{8x+2x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{8x-2x}{2}\right)-2\sin\left(\frac{7x+3x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{7x-3x}{2}\right)=0$$
>   $$2\sin 5x\cos 3x-2\sin 5x\cos 2x=0$$
>   $$\sin 5x(\cos 3x-\cos 2x)=0$$
>   $$\sin 5x=0\implies 5x=k\pi$$$$ \color{red}{x=\frac{k\pi}{5}=36k}$$
>   or $$\cos 3x-\cos 2x=0\implies \cos 3x=\cos 2x$$ $$3x=2k\pi\pm 2x$$ 
>   $$ 3x=2k\pi+2x\implies \color{red}{x=2k\pi=360k}$$
>   or 
>   $$ 3x=2k\pi-2x\implies \color{red}{x=\frac{2k\pi}{5}=72 k}$$

Where, $k$ is any integer

Comment: How is this a hint? What would you add, if you were to write a full solution?

Comment: But the formula is: sinx+siny=2sin((x+y)/2)*cos((x-y)/2) . Not 2sin(..)*sin(...)

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are correct.